# Check if columns are NULL or contains NULL in table. - MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Following is my table `(TestTable)` where `Column_3` is `NULL`.

```
Column_1 Column_2 Column_3
-------- -------- --------
1        2        NULL
1        3        NULL
5        6        NULL
```

As per functionality, user can select one or more `columns`. 
For example, if user selects `Column_3 & Column_2` where `Column_3` is `NULL`. I want to tell user that `Column_3` is `NULL`.

Query : Works for single column

```
if exists(select * from TestTable where Column_3 is null)
    print 'Yes'
else
    print 'No'
```

Result :

```
Yes
```

Query : For multiple Columns (not working)

```
declare @columns nvarchar(max), @tableName nvarchar(max), @query nvarchar(max)

set @columns = 'Column_3, Column_2'
set @tableName = 'TestTable'
set @query = 'select * from (select ' + @columns + ' from ' + @tableName + ') as Result'
print @query
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @query
```

Here

`@query = select * from (select Column_3, Column_2 from TestTable) as Result`

Above query gives me result for those two columns. I'm not sure how can I check `NULL` in this query for multiple columns. If I add `IS NULL` (like I did for single column) after or before last parenthesis it gives me `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'is'.` error. How can I achieve my goal in this situation?

Comment: `if exists(select * from TestTable where Column_3 is null or Column_2 is null)`

Comment: Well the multiple column will be `Column_3, Column_2` in format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

we can check with the help of `IN` like

```
...WHERE NULL IN (Column_2, Column_3)
```

from your comment `Well the multiple column will be Column_3, Column_2 in format`
might be this is helpful for you

```
select * from (select Column_3, Column_2 from @temp where null in (Column_3, Column_2)) as Result
```

Comment: In MySQL, expression `NULL IN (Column_2, Column_3)` always evaluates to `NULL`; "To comply with the SQL standard, IN() returns NULL [...] if the expression on the left hand side is NULL" ~ https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_in

Answer (score 5):

## Two Solutions (Column is All NULLs, Column Contains Some NULLs)

I have slightly altered your original example in order to provide two solutions:

```
Column_1 Column_2 Column_3
-------- -------- --------
1        2        NULL
1        NULL     NULL
5        6        NULL
```

**First**, test for NULLs and count them:

```
select 
    sum(case when Column_1 is null then 1 else 0 end) as Column_1, 
    sum(case when Column_2 is null then 1 else 0 end) as Column_2, 
    sum(case when Column_3 is null then 1 else 0 end) as Column_3,
from TestTable
```

Yields a count of NULLs:

```
Column_1  Column_2  Column_3
0         1         3
```

Where the result is 0, there are no NULLs.

**Second**, let's count the non-NULLs:

```
select 
    sum(case when Column_1 is null then 0 else 1 end) as Column_1, 
    sum(case when Column_2 is null then 0 else 1 end) as Column_2, 
    sum(case when Column_3 is null then 0 else 1 end) as Column_3,
from TestTable
```

...But because we're counting non-NULLs here, this can be simplified to:

```
select 
    count(Column_1) as Column_1, 
    count(Column_2) as Column_2, 
    count(Column_3) as Column_3,
from TestTable
```

Either one yields:

```
Column_1  Column_2  Column_3
3         2         0
```

Where the result is 0, the column is entirely made up of NULLs.

If you only need to check a given column, then TOP 1 is quicker because it should stop at the first hit:

```
select count(*) from (select top 1 'There is at least one NULL' AS note from TestTable where Column_3 is NULL) a
```

0 = There are no NULLs, 1 = There is at least one NULL

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT TOP 1 'There is at least one non-NULL' AS note FROM sat_data_active_season_group WHERE season_group IS NOT NULL) a
```

0 = They are all NULL, 1 = There is at least one non-NULL

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try as below.

You can find the null able column by using CASE.

```
Select CASE WHEN Column_3 IS NULL THEN 'Column 3 is null' ELSE Column_3 END as Column3,
CASE WHEN Column_2 IS NULL THEN 'Column 2 is null' ELSE Column_2 END as Column2
From TableName
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need a `CASE` statement. [Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)

Example:

```
SELECT CASE
        WHEN ISNULL(Column_3) THEN -- do something
        WHEN NOT ISNULL(Column_3) THEN -- do something else
       AS Column_3 -- or some other name
```